# how to make IntlPhoneField ignore taps but it's suffix icon to respond to taps in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
                            IntlPhoneField(
                                enabled: editable,
                                controller: _textEditingController,
                                showCountryFlag: false,
                                initialValue:
                                    _textEditingController.value.toString(),
                                initialCountryCode: countries
                                    .firstWhere((element) =>
                                        "+${element.dialCode}" ==
                                        "${PreferenceUtils.getString(Constants.countryCode)}")
                                    .code,
                                dropdownTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: editable
                                        ? CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(context,
                                            lightColor: ColorCode.black,
                                            darkColor: ColorCode.lightGreyFont)
                                        : CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(context,
                                            lightColor: ColorCode.grey_400,
                                            darkColor: ColorCode.lightGreyFont),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 16),
                                dropdownIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                  color: CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(context,
                                      lightColor: ColorCode.black,
                                      darkColor: ColorCode.lightGreyFont),
                                  size: 4.h,
                                ),
                                flagsButtonMargin:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                disableLengthCheck: false,
                                dropdownIconPosition: IconPosition.trailing,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: editable
                                        ? CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(context,
                                            lightColor: ColorCode.black,
                                            darkColor: ColorCode.lightGreyFont)
                                        : CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(context,
                                            lightColor: ColorCode.grey_400,
                                            darkColor: ColorCode.lightGreyFont),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 16),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(
                                      context,
                                      lightColor: ColorCode.colorWhite,
                                      darkColor: ColorCode.textFieldDark),
                                  suffixIcon: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      splashColor: ColorCode.transparent,
                                      highlightColor: ColorCode.transparent,
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          ignoreTap = false;
                                        });
                                        verifyMobileNumberAlert();
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Change",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: editable
                                                ? CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(
                                                    context,
                                                    lightColor:
                                                        ColorCode.primaryColor,
                                                    darkColor:
                                                        ColorCode.buttonEnabled)
                                                : CommonFunctions.getThemeColor(
                                                    context,
                                                    lightColor:
                                                        ColorCode.grey_400,
                                                    darkColor: ColorCode
                                                        .buttonEnabled),
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                    minHeight: 0,
                                    minWidth: 0,
                                    maxHeight: 50,
                                  ),

                                  // labelText: Constants.mobileNumber,
                                  hintText: Constants.mobileNumber,
                                  iconColor: ColorCode.black,
                                  focusColor: ColorCode.black,
                                  labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: ColorCode.placeholderLabelText),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color: ColorCode.placeholderDefault),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(47.0)),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color: ColorCode.placeholderDefault),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(47.0)),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color: ColorCode.placeholderDefault),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(49.0)),
                                  counterStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: ColorCode.transparent),
                                ),
                                readOnly: true,
                                onCountryChanged: (val) {
                                  _textEditingController.text = "";
                                  basicDetailsFormBloc.mobile.updateValue('');
                                },
                              ),
```

This is my phone field ... I want to ignore the taps on it except the suffix icon. I tried wrapping the field with IgnorePointer but it ignores taps on suffix icon as well. How to achieve it? I also tried AbsorbPointer it also behaves like IgnorePointer. On tapping the suffix icon it shouldn't ignore taps ... but on tapping the country code and phone number it should ignore taps because it shouldn't open country list on tap of country code.

Comment: Set TextField's readonly paramter to true (readonly: true) and wrap your suffix Icon with gesturedetector or inkwell for getting touch response.

Comment: I have done that.. but still it doesn't work.. It opens the country dropdown menu as soon I click on the country code